# Datatable print does not work properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$("#gridExtractReport").DataTable({
  destroy: true,
  searching: true,
  lengthChange: false,
  "paging": false,
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'print',
      customize: function (win) {
        $(win.document.body)
          .css('font-size', '10pt')
          .prepend(result);
        $(win.document.body).find('table')
          .addClass('compact')
          .css('font-size', 'inherit');
      }
    }
    ,
    {
      extend: 'excel',
      customize: function (doc) {
        $(doc.body)
          .css('font-size', '9pt')
          .prepend(result);
        $(doc.body).find('table')
          .addClass('compact')
          .css('font-size', 'inherit');
      },
      title: accountText + "(" + startDate + "/" + endDate + ") Daire Ektresi"
    }
  ],
  "language": {
    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.10/i18n/Turkish.json"
  }
});
```

I can get Excel export but it shows empty page after I click print however my grid is not empty. Here you can see the image of my empty page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> please add following js files and css to your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

`<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>`

and add below code into function:

```
buttons: [
        {

            extend: 'print',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible',
            }
        }
    ],
    columnDefs: [ {
        targets: -1,
        visible: false
    } ]
```